# Map function at Haskell

Tags: haskell

The question : Define the function setElements, which takes a list indxs of pairs of (n, x) (where n is an
Int), and a list xs, and for each pair (n, x) it sets the n’th element in xs to be x.
If a pair contains in its first component a negative index, or an index larger than the
length of xs, ignore this pair.
If the indxs list contains more than one pair with the same key (e.g., [(1,'a'),(1,'b')]), the
last occurrence of the key will be the one that holds.
Examples:

```
setElements [(1, 'a'), (-4, 't'), (3, 'b')] "#####" = "#a#b#"
setElements [(2, 50), (50, 2)] [8, 7, 6, 5, 4] = [8, 7, 50, 5, 4]
setElements [(3, 'a'),(5, 'b'),(3, 'c')] "wwwwwww" = "wwwcwbw"
```

my code:

```
--1.a
setElement:: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
setElement n x xs = (take n xs ++ x:tail(drop n xs))

--b

setElements :: [(Int,b)] -> [b] -> [b]
setElements (x:xs) = map (setElement (fst x) (snd x) [b])
```

Comment: Hello @Ailon Livny! You appear to be a Haskell beginner, or at least very confused about many parts of how Haskell works. I would *strongly* suggest reading a beginners' book, such as [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) thoroughly before you attempt something like this – your parse error is far from the only problem with this code. Good luck!

Comment: Your `do` syntax is wrong, there are no `|` there, but much more importantly, you do not need to use `do` there! You should use `do`, `return` and other monadic stuff only when you are working inside some monad. Here, you are not using any monad (well, technically `[]` is a monad, but here you do not need it to use it as a monad). Try using recursion instead. Further, `[b]` is wrong here, since it only matches against lists having exactly one element.

Comment: Please look again at my code

Comment: You can't use `map` for this. Either you use some fold, or you need to recurse. Something like `setElements ((n,x):xs) ys = setElements xs (setElement n x ys)`. Also add a case for the empty list.

Answer (score 1):

The setElement function is almost right, but the standard way of doing it is.

```
 take n xs ++ [x] ++ drop (n + 1) xs
```

But again this is not taking care of negative n. This can be easilt done using pattern mathing.

```
 setElement n x xs | n < 0 =  xs 
                   | otherwise =  take n xs ++ [x] ++ drop (n + 1) xs
```

For setElements  you will have to think recursively. The function should simply return the second argument when first argument is empty.

```
setElements [] ys = ys
```

When the first list is not empty

- take the first pair and manipulate the second argument
- the result of the above should be send recursively to rest of the first argument

  `setElements ((x,b):xs) ys = let ps = ...
                               in setElements ....`

Fill in the blanks. Its very simple actually.